# Bind array of classes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, bind

Is it possible to simplify the following jQuery using a for loop?

```
$("#nav li a.h").mouseover(
  function () {
    if($(".content.h").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".content.h").fadeIn('fast');
    }
  }
);
$("#nav li a.e").mouseover(
  function () {
    if($(".content.e").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".content.e").fadeIn('fast');
    }
  }
);
$("#nav li a.o").mouseover(
  function () {
    if($(".content.o").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".content.o").fadeIn('fast');
    }
  }
);
```

I tried this, but no luck:

```
var pg = ["h","e","o"];
for (var i = 0; i < pg.length; i++) {
    $("#nav li a.pg[i]").mouseover(
      function () {
        if($(".content.pg[i]").is(":hidden")) {
            $(".content.pg[i]").fadeIn('fast');
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg[i]` inside quotes will not work as a variable, you need to append it to the selector string using `+`.

**More optimizations**: The $.each method is fast and good to use when looping, and you don’t need to check if `elem.is(':hidden')`, just include `:hidden` in the selector:

```
$.each(["h","e","o"], function(i, id) {
    $("#nav li a."+id).mouseover(function() {
        $(".content."+id+":hidden").fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 both for the simplicity and for the fact that this solution creates appropriate closures so that the `id` variable isn't shared between each of the mouseover handlers (the way that a standard for loop index `i` would be).

Answer (score 2):

Don't add `pg[i]` to the string, because it won't be interpreted as JavaScript variables. Instead, use this:

```
var pg = ["h", "e", "o"]
for(var i=0; i<pg.length; i++){
    (function(current){
        $("#nav li a."+current).mouseover(
            function () {
                if($(".content."+current).is(":hidden")) {
                    $(".content."+current).fadeIn('fast');
                }
            }
        );
    })(pg[i])
}
```

Comment: I posted basically the same answer, but then I deleted it because I realised that each of the mouseover functions is accessing the same `current` variable so at the time they're actually executed they'll all be using `current` as "o". (In my case I didn't bother with the extra variable, I just had pg[i], but it's the same problem.) EDIT: David's answer solves this problem.

Comment: I've fixed the closure issue.